# Signurl command requires the pyopenssl library in gsutil in google storage in creatiing signed URL

Tags: google-cloud-storage, python-2.6, pyopenssl

I am trying Create a signed URL with gsutil .
following is the command 
 **$ gsutil signurl -d 10m path/to/privatekey.p12 gs://bucket/foo**

mentioned in site  https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol

I also issued a same like command with my bucket name and object as below

**gsutil signurl -d 10m C:\Users\Desktop\javascript\service\4e263da.p12 gs://code-sample/File1**

but i got following error

> "signurl command requires the pyopenssl library try pip install
>   pyopenssl or easy_install pyopenssl"

.So,i installed PyOpenSSL for window  from here

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL/0.13 .My python version is 2.6.Still i am  getting same error in running the command. So my question why command signurl is still not recognized after i installed pyopenssl in gsutil

Comment: When you run the Python interpreter, can you `import OpenSSL` ?

Answer (score 4):

Install with

```
pip3 install --user pyopenssl
```

and it should works (especially if you're running in the cloud console)!

Answer (score 2):

was getting this error and tried a variety of python pyopenssl options, but this worked for me in the end, on:
Debian 10 with
Google Cloud SDK 345.0.0
gsutil version: 4.63

*sudo apt-get install python3-openssl*

Answer (score 2):

When using Python 3 and gsutil `5.27` or older, install `pyopenssl` as

```
pip3 install --user pyopenssl==23.2.0
```

The `gsutil` is trying to import `load_pkcs12` from `OpenSSL.crypto` that was removed in the `23.3.0` version

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Python v3.7.5 and gsutil v4.46.

To fix the issue I installed `pyopenssl` for Python 2: `pip2 install --user pyopenssl`

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be because you are using 64 bit system and python
Working with egenix-pyopenssl-0.13.4.1.0.1.9.win32-py2.7 - 32bit and python 32 bit solved this problem for me... Even google document recommends use of 32bits

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Python 2.7 with same issue.
ProcMon was showing that the bundled Python was being executed (%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\python.exe) and not Python in the path variable.

I renamed the 'bundledpython' directory and re-ran 'gsutil signurl' and it ran successfully.

Note: this is after the crypto library was installed (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/crypto)

Answer (score 0):

A recent version of pyopenssl (2.23.3) seems to have broken gsutil: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/1753
If you encounter this, you may want to revert to an older version.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is rooted in the `gsutil` shell script and the python libraries.  The `gsutil` script expects Python 2.

```
pip3 uninstall pyOpenSSL
pip2 install pyOpenSSL
```

After the above I could successfully sign URLs using `gsutil`